# AWS S3- Policy Condition Failed- eq key

Tags: html, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on uploading files to s3 from the website. I get all needed information from my nodejs server which uses `aws sdk`. The problem I have is that it generates a key which I have to use in my form like this:

```
   <input type="hidden" name="key" value="xxx" /><br />
```

And it works, but every file I upload has the name of the 'key'. If I change it to sth like this:

```
   <input type="hidden" name="key" value="xxx/name.jpg" /><br />
```

It gives me an error:

```
Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$key", "xxx"]
```

Here are my conditions to generate the policy:

```
Conditions: [
        ['starts-with', '$key', ''],
        ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"],
        {"x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"}
      ]
```

How can I set the name of the file?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. The problem was that in parameters object which is passed this function:

```
s3.createPresignedPost(params, function(err, data)
```

I had parameter Fields which included key:

```
  Fields: {
    key: key,
  },
```

Simply deleting it fixed the problem