# How to use aws s3 createPresignedPost with ksm encryption

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I have found aws documentation for doing this with Java, and a couple of scattered references for javascript developers, but I have not been able to accomplish this without receiving access denied from aws. I've tried a lot of different variations.

To make matters a little worse, my development environment is a proprietary framework that handles a lot of the role and credentialling in the background, but I have been able to identify that the ksm policy is the sticking point, and I have not found the solution.

I've tried passing parameters to the signing process:

```
const params = {
    Bucket: targetBucket,
    ServerSideEncryption: 'aws:kms',
    SSEKMSKeyId: keyId,
    Conditions: [{ acl: 'private' }, { key: filepath } ]
};
return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    clientS3.createPresignedPost(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            rej(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
            res({ data, filepath, encryption, bucket });
        }
    });
});
```

That didn't work. Access denied. (Yes, I included these values in the formdata, to ensure a correctly signed request.)

I also tried adding headers to the post request itself, via:

```
return axios
  .post(response.data.url, formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id': response.encryption,
      'x-amz-server-side-encryption-context': bucketArn
    },
    ....
```

Access Denied. I've tried mixing and matching approaches. I can make things worse by breaking the signature, but I can't land the encrypted file or find documentation to accomplish this.

**UPDATE** : I have verified that the access role has KMS permissions to Encrypt & GenerateDataKey, as per jarmod; AND I have verified that removing the encryption policies on the bucket allow the upload no problem.

The policy described is:

```
{
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:PutObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[[ bucket name ]]/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLikeIfExists": {
                "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id": "[[ kms arn ]]"
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**

After adding the header `x-amz-server-side-encryption: aws:kms` I got no better result. The full request headers are:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 307546
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary4B20k5OmUGzGhYoV
Host: s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
Origin: http://localhost:8888
Referer: http://localhost:8888/ 
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
x-amz-server-side-encryption: aws:kms
x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id: [[ full arn of kms key ]] 
x-amz-server-side-encryption-context: arn:aws:s3:::[[ bucket name ]]/*
```

The response headers are:

```
Request URL: https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/[[ bucket name ]] 
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Remote Address: 52.92.145.80:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8888
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Mon, 05 Dec 2022 02:07:11 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
x-amz-id-2: [[ ugly amz string ]]
x-amz-request-id: [[ shorter amz string ]]
```

The response payload is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message>. 
<RequestId>[[ same as header request id ]]</RequestId>. 
<HostId>[[ same as long amz id in headers ]] </HostId></Error>
```

Finally, the payload of the formdata is:

```
acl: private
key: [[ filename ]]
bucket: [[ bucket ]]
X-Amz-Algorithm: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
X-Amz-Credential: [[credential string ]]
X-Amz-Date: 20221205T020711Z
X-Amz-Security-Token: [[ token ]]
Policy: [[ policy string ]]
X-Amz-Signature: [[ signature string ]]
file: (binary)
```

Comment: Can you get this to work without KMS? Just checking that works before adding the complexity of KMS. Do the credentials you are using to sign this POST request have the relevant KMS permissions (kms:Encrypt and kms:GenerateDataKey, iirc) for the KMS key id?

Comment: Yes, if I remove the policy from the s3 bucket everything works fine.

Comment: KMS permissions of the IAM principal that's signing the request?

Comment: In other contexts, the role is decrypting on demand; the iam policies are GetKeyPolicy & PutKeyPolicy -- I don't actually see options for kms:Encrypt in IAM/KMS at all... the role has all s3 permissions. // Update I found the Encrypt option, have turned it on, and am retesting.

Comment: When I turn on the Encrypt option for the role, I get a 403 response *without* a payload; turning off Encrypt I get a 403 response *with* a payload, and the payload says access denied.

Comment: AND... with Encrypt AND GenerateDataKey both turned on, I am back to 403 response *with* a payload, same payload.

Comment: I have retried all permutations of formdata params & post headers to no benefit.

Comment: I'd expect the client to send the header `x-amz-server-side-encryption: aws:kms` as well as the KMS key id in `x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id` (you appear to be doing the latter explicitly). And for the IAM principal performing the signing to have `kms:generateDataKey` on the relevant KMS key. Check the headers sent include `x-amz-server-side-encryption`. If that doesn't help, maybe update the post with (sanitized) headers that your client is actually sending.

Comment: Look at this post, may provide a hint (although his using server side encryption not KMS service),  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51757774/aws-s3-policy-condition-failed-eq-key

Comment: @jarmod -- post updated with headers; I don't see anything helpful in there. Note the kind of ugly policy on this bucket (not my design) -- the policy works for s3 put operations; not sure if it might be the problem with this pre-signed url operation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of a S3 Presigned URL upload with Customer-managed KMS key encryption.  I used the JS SDK v3 [@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_s3_request_presigner.html) package for signing and Node18's native fetch.

I tested it with two Bucket Policy scenarios: (a) your bucket policy verbatim (b) the policy from this [AWS Knowledge Center Q&A](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-bucket-store-kms-encrypted-objects/).  The upload succeeds against both policies with the headers below.  As expected, it fails with a `403` response if the required headers are removed.

```js
const body = "Uploaded with a pre-signed URL and Customer-managed KMS key!";
const keyId = "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:123456789012:key/231389a0-...";

const command = new PutObjectCommand({
  Bucket: "my-bucket-123456789012-us-east-1",
  Key: `myFile.txt`,
  ServerSideEncryption: "aws:kms",
  SSEKMSKeyId: keyId, 
  Body: body,
});

const url = await getSignedUrl(client, command, { expiresIn: 3600 });

const res = await fetch(url, {
  method: "PUT",
  headers: {
    "x-amz-server-side-encryption": "aws:kms",
    "x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id": keyId,
  },
  body,
});
```

Comment: Hmmm... you need to put the body in the url signing request?? That's kind of weird; but in that case, I can really just post the whole file to the service and have the service make the S3 call directly. It seems to defeat the purpose of url signing!

Comment: @BluntJackson  No. The body is ignored when generating the pre-signed URL.